# Can the edit approval rules be improved?

Tags: discussion

When a post has a suggested edit, it takes several votes to approve the edit, even by people who could themselves edit posts without review. While the edit is pending, I can't directly edit the post either. This is counter-intuitive and drives me a little nuts, because I want to see the post edited and improved.

I propose to change the edit rules that an already approved editor can, with a single vote, approve or disapprove pending edits, so that the post is again open for further edits.

Comment: Don't "improve edit" and "reject and edit" do what you want? Described toward the end of this FAQ post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/133299

Comment: I did not go through the queue, I clicked on the edit button directly from the post, and was not offered the reject or improve options.

Comment: There's not a suggested edit in the queue here to try it on, but I tried on another site, and when clicking on the edit link I do indeed get shown the item to review, including the improve/reject+edit options. (And in any case, it sounds like in this case, you didn't even cast your single vote, so I'm not sure that changing the number of reviews required would've fixed it, unless someone else happened to have already reviewed it.)

Comment: I did cast my vote, not sure what gave you the impression that I didn't.

Comment: You said you didn't go through the queue, and that you didn't see the reject/improve options (which are presented directly next to the approve/reject vote options), so I assumed you hadn't seen any review options at all. My misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

I very much don't like the idea of requiring fewer reviewers in general, for much [the same reasons as Joe W mentioned](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1825/409). When people actually edit a post, they tend to put in some effort - they're doing a complex task (editing the text of the post), their name's going on it. But when going through the review queue, and only making a simple yes/no decision, it's very very easy to skim quickly and miss things.

If suggested edits aren't getting reviewed quickly enough, it's because people are not often enough going into the suggested edit queue and doing the reviews.

Here's a post with a pending suggested edit:

[image: post with pending suggested edit]

And here's what happens when I click edit:

[image: in-page suggested edit review]

(Screenshots are from another site, since there's nothing in the queue here right now.)

At this point you can cast your one approve/reject vote and see if it's enough to finish the review. You can also "improve edit" or "reject and edit", if you have edits you want to make, and you're willing to make sure the entire post is in a good state after your edit (i.e. that you haven't introduced issues by accepting the suggestions, or that you haven't left issues unaddressed by rejecting the suggestions).

Answer (score 3):

This is something that is unlikely to happen as it has been shown on other sites that people who have the edit privilege are not always properly reviewing suggested edits. Because of this the rule is in place that either multiple people need to review it or the poster can approve it themselves.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271889/why-cant-i-approve-suggested-edits-single-handedly

I know this is frustrating but I do agree that we don't want someone just robo reviewing the suggested edits and having a lot of bad edits go through.